# A characterization of maps that are homotopic relative to $A$ over $S$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A & \rightarrow & X \\
i\downarrow  & & \downarrow p \\ 
B & \xrightarrow{v} & S
\end{array} $$ be a commutative diagram of simplicial sets, with $p$ an inner fibration. Two solutions $f,g$ to this lifting problems are called homotopic relative to $A$ over $S$ provided that they are equivalent in the fiber of the map $$X^B\rightarrow X^A\times_{S^A}S^B.$$

Now, it is easy to see that this imply the existence of a map $\Delta^1\times B\rightarrow X$ satisfying certain obvious properties (spelled out, for instance, here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/minimal+inner+fibration), amongst which is that the map $$F|_{\{b\}\times\Delta^1}\rightarrow X_{v(b)}$$ is an equivalence for every $b$.

How can you prove the converse? I found an argument for the case when $A=\emptyset$ and $S=*$, but not for the general case.

NB: Chances are it is proven at some point in HTT, but so far, I have only found this assertion without proof.

Comment: I followed the ncatlab link in your question. In order to match the exposition there, do you mean $F: B\times \Delta[1] \to X$ rather than $\Delta^1 \times X \to X$? In that ncatlab page, it already says the existence of $F$ is equivalent to the first meaning of homotopic relative to $A$ over $S$.

Comment: You're definitely right! I know that these are equivalent, but I can't figure out a proof for the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fact is indeed standard. Because $\Delta^1 \times B$ is a cylinder object for $B$, the equivalent formulation (the hypothesis of the converse direction you're asking for) is just explicitly spelling out the homotopy that shows the two maps are equivalent in that fiber. A good place to learn about relative homotopy in a general category $C$ (including $C = sSet/S$) is Isaev's paper [On Fibrant Objects in Model Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4327.pdf). Specifically, Proposition 2.4 might help you (and, the picture later on that page might help you unpack what both notions mean). The argument you wrote down for $S = \ast$ will also work fiber by fiber to prove the general case. Isaev's paper will help you shift from thinking about $A = \emptyset$ to thinking about a general object $A$.

To be even clearer, using the order from Lurie's book and the ncatlab page:

- The first two conditions on $F$ are saying it's a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.
- The next condition is saying it's a homotopy *over $S$*.
- The next condition is saying it's a homotopy *relative to $A$*.
- The last condition is giving the equivalence in the fiber.

This information explicitly tells me I can deform $f$ to $g$ in the fiber of $X^B \to X^A \times_{S^A} S^B$.